# Calling child user-control's function

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a window.

```
<Window 
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        x:Class="GamingClient.UserInterface.MenuPartieRapide"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GamingClient.UserInterface">

        <local:MapCarrousel />

</Window>
```

and this is the MapCarrousel user-control

```
<UserControl
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="GamingClient.UserInterface.MapCarrousel" d:DesignWidth="1002" d:DesignHeight="122">

</UserControl>
```

And here is the code behind the userControl

```
 public int GetMapId()
 {
    .... Return some Int
 }
```

I tried adding a name to my MapCarrousel in my Window

```
<local:MapCarrousel Name="Test" />
```

Therefore I tried calling it in my Window.xaml.cs

```
void function Test()
{
       Test.GetMapId();
}
```

1. Test is not accessible in the namespace? The intellisense doesn't recognize it.
2. Following #1, I can't call a function on undefined object...

I then tried the following :  Adding x:name inside of the user-control and calling that x:name inside one of the function in my Window.xaml.cs.

Same result has before.

Question is : How do I call a public function on a user-control which is a child of the namespace/object I am in if that user-control is not created dynamicly (ie new User-Control()) but added threw the designer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you tried to set the `Name` property on your `MapCarrousel` control, you should have had an error something like this:

> Error  2   Because 'MS.Internal.Design.Metadata.ReflectionTypeNode' is implemented in the same assembly, you must set the x:Name attribute rather than the MS.Internal.Design.Metadata.ReflectionPropertyNode attribute.

That is telling you that you cannot do this:

```
<local:MapCarrousel Name="Test" />
```

As the error tells you, you need to do this instead:

```
<local:MapCarrousel x:Name="Test" />
```

Then you will be able to call:

```
Test.GetMapId();
```