# Wpf Name "interactiveGrid" does not exists in the current context

Tags: c#, wpf

I have some question about wpf.
There is a my class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace RatesScenarios.Controls
{
    class InteractiveGrid : Grid, IDisposable
    {
    //...
    }
}
```

When I add it to xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="RatesScenarios.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:RatesScenarios.Controls"
        Title="RatesScenarios" MinHeight="400" Width="700" Background="SteelBlue" SizeToContent="Manual">
```

and below

```
<Grid Background="White">
<Border BorderBrush="#CCCCCC" BorderThickness="1" Margin="7,10,7,10" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
<controls:InteractiveGrid Name="interactiveGrid" ShowGridLines="True" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
</controls:InteractiveGrid>
</Border>
</Grid>
```

when build project excepts error: Name "interactiveGrid" does not exists in the current context

```
namespace RatesScenarios
{
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
      private void Refresh()
      {
         interactiveGrid.Children.Clear();
      }
   }
}
```

Why it happen?

Comment: Have you tried adding public to the definition of your control? public class InteractiveGrid

Comment: Yes, "public class InteractiveGrid" also does not work. Definition "class InteractiveGrid" must work because it declared in single assembly

Comment: Have you tried x:Name="interactiveGrid" instead of Name="interactiveGrid" ?

Comment: Yes, "x:Name" resolve my problem. Thank you, rauland.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If somebody else gets this error without any indication as to why it’s happening closing and opening the .XAML file suggests the following:

```
Error 2 Because 'MS.Internal.Design.Metadata.ReflectionTypeNode' is   
implemented in the same assembly, you must set the x:Name   
attribute rather than the  
MS.Internal.Design.Metadata.ReflectionPropertyNode attribute.
```

There are similar questions on SO:
[Calling child user-control's function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22209133/calling-child-user-controls-function)

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's a silly question, but have you declared public constructor for InteractiveGrid?
Do you invoke InitializeComponent() method in MainWindow  constructor?

Answer (score 0):

There is existing code, does not build

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace RatesScenarios.Controls
{
    public class InteractiveGrid : Grid, IDisposable
    {
    #region IDisposable Members
        public void Dispose()
        {

        }
    #endregion

        private DataCell selectedCell;

        public DataCell SelectedCell
        {
            get { return selectedCell; }
        }

        public InteractiveGrid()
        {

        }

        public void Build(List<string> columnsHeaders, List<string> rowsHeaders, List<DataCell> dataCells)
        {

        }

        public void SelectCell(DataCell dataCell)
        {
            selectedCell = dataCell;
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
//..
}
```

Comment: Is this your solution? If so, please add some remarks about the steps you undertook to fix your problem. If not, you should edit your question the next time.